# i want to fetch olx data using node js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch

how to *retrieve* **olx** data  hit data when documentation is not given  ???using **nodejs**

Comment: great quote! where is it from?

Comment: Hi daya, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you [edit] your question to explain what you are trying to do, and how you are trying to do it? It's not very clear what it is you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `npm module` to get data

`npm install olx`

Check the details [`here`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/olx)